# How to Resolve 'not found: object anorm' for play 2.4.3

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, dependencies, anorm

I'm using **play 2.4.3**, When I import anorm like

import anorm._ 
   import anorm.SqlParser._

this brings up the error message below in the IDE...

> not found: object anorm

But my project will execute (without throwing any error).

**Dependencies**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.3.6")
```

**Editor**

> eclipse Luna

**scala version**

> scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

**Activator**

> Version 1.3.6

**OS**

> Windows 8

Comment: looks like an IDE problem, did/can you try building with sbt outside ide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imports are incorrect - they should be:

```
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
```

Note the difference on the second import.

HTH