# How to Resolve not found: object anorm for play 2.5.8

Tags: scala, playframework, eclipse-luna, anorm

I'm using Play 2.5.8, Given below Anorm header files using in models but it's throwing error, How do I resolve it. Already I tried this link but no use [How to Resolve 'not found: object anorm' for play 2.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139844/how-to-resolve-not-found-object-anorm-for-play-2-4-3/33454395)

[image]

**Scala Version**

```
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

**Dependencies**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.5.1",
   evolutions
)
```

**Editor**

```
Eclipse Luna
```

**OS**

```
Ubuntu 16.04 / Windows 7
```

Build.sbt

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.8")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

Comment: can u provide plugins.sbt in your project

Comment: `plugins.sbt` is irrelevant for me, try to compile directly using SBT, if it works that's an IDE issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try referring the Maven repository and confirm that you are using the correct dependency

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/play/anorm_2.9.1

copy paste the dependency from there